# Using Multiple GetComponent<Image>() ----

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class HPsc
{
    public static Image HP_Bar_Green;
    public static Image HP_Bar_Red; // Allows me to initialize the images in Unity

    private void Start()
    {
        HP_Bar_Green = GetComponent<Image>();
        HP_Bar_Red = GetComponent<Image>(); //How I grab the images upon startup
    }
}
```

Both variables are being filled with HP_Bar_Green. How can I prevent this from happening? Also why does this happen?

I have tried attaching this.GetComponent(); to both and I've tried to write an IF statement to prevent this from happening but with no luck.

```
if (HP_Bar_Red == HP_Bar_Green)
{
    HP_Bar_Red = GetComponent<Image>();

    Debug.Log("RED "+HP_Bar_Red);
    HP_Bar_Red.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

All help and suggestions ARE appreciated! I'm really stuck here!

**** UPDATE ****

I decided to move the HP_Bar_Red to the EnemyDetection script. That way I can make it PUBLIC and manually insert it into Unity inspector via script. However, when I press PLAY, the image vanishes from the script field, however, it still appears on the screen. I can then put the image back into the field on the inspector whilst the game is in play mode and the script works fine. So why is the image not being accepted?

```
public class EnemyDetection : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image HP_Bar_Red;

    private void Start()
    {

        HP_Bar_Red = GetComponent<Image>();
        Debug.Log("RED " + HP_Bar_Red);

        // HP_Bar_Red.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        HP_Bar_Red.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your case it is better to name your GameObejcts correctly and use GameObject.Find("HP_Bar_Green").GetComponent<Image>();

Comment: @GameGenerator that would also work.

Comment: Has an error message saying that I cant access with an instant reference; qualify it with a type instead. What does that mean?

Comment: You have to use `public class HPsc : MonoBehaviour {...` and add this component to a gameobject in your scene. Also you need the right usings. Best way: create a new script in unity, add `using UnityEngine.UI` on top.

Comment: If I make them PUBLIC nonstatic, then it breaks my code when I try to inherit the constructors in my other script. My current code works, minus the one variable not getting placed in the variable. There must be some while loop or if statement to where I can force the HP_BAR_Red into the variable. They are named according to how I imported them into Unity by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    //Make sure that the name fits to the .cs file name and add this script to a GameObejct in the scene
    public class HPsc : MonoBehaviour 
    {
        public static Image HP_Bar_Green;
        public static Image HP_Bar_Red;

        //Add your images here in the scene - Inspector:
        public Image imgGreen;
        public Image imgRed;

        private void Awake()
        {
            HP_Bar_Green = imgRed; //Make them accessable over the static variables
            HP_Bar_Red = imgGreen;
        }

        //Test (also usable in another class):
        private void Start()
        {
            Debug.Log(HPsc.HP_Bar_Red != null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple `Image` components attached to the `gameObject` correct?

If that's the case, you need to use [`GetComponets<T>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponents.html) and use the returned `Component[]`:

```
public class HPsc
{    
    private Component[] _images;

    void Start()
    {
        Images = GetComponents<Image>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Assuming the order is correct, you could also make some sort of 
        // id property to search the array with.
        var green = images[0];
        var red = images[1];

        // Do something with the images.
    }
}
```

Comment: These two images actually are for a Healthbar in a game I'm working on. Each variable is for each image. The problem is that both are getting only the green bar image. I'm not sure how to make a list and populate it using Unity, but I'll look into it now. I'm dynamically grabbing the images with GetComponent<>() because my variables are set as STATIC.  I do like your list idea. Thanks!

Comment: Dont you have to inherit from MonoBehaviour? GetComponent only works on the GameObject the Script (MonoBehaviour) is lying on. Gloaballly you can use **FindObjectsOfType<Image>()** in a script

Comment: FindObjectsOfType is for list, no? As of now, I would have to GetComponents<>() to fill the variables, then push them into a list. Then pull them back out. The problem here is that If I could get both of the images, I wouldn't need the list lol It would be easier if I could use a public nonstatic, but since I'm inheriting them from another class, this just won't work with my current code setup. I'd hate to scrap the code because it does work for the most part.